# How to create my own buildpack for Heroku (gauge)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, heroku, buildpack, gauge

I have an automation project where I use jave/maven/gauge. And I want to run it headless on Heroku. But the Gauge framework is not supported by Heroku.

So, how can I create buildpack for gauge? Or if it has been created, can you share it with me?

https://github.com/getgauge/gauge

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This buildpack is made to use Gauge test automation framework in Heroku (runtime). Make sure your $PATH variable includes /app/.gauge before using it.
This buildpack also installs all gauge plugins. You can remove the plugins you don't want by editing the compile file. For that, you will need to fork this project and commit to the new version.

cp -r /app/.gauge $1 This command in the compile file copies the gauge files to the build folder and the gauge becomes available in the runtime. So, we can use Gauge in Procfile.

an example procfile: worker: mvn gauge:execute

Installation
You can add it to /Settings/Buildpacks section.

https://github.com/erdemkiiliic/heroku-buildpack-gauge

Also, you can add with simple command.

heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/erdemkiiliic/heroku-buildpack-gauge.git -a myapp